# MySQL open multiple connections

Tags: mysql, parallel-processing, mysql-workbench, database-performance

Is there any ways to open a new MySQLconnection from a stored procedure to improve execution time.

For eg: I have three stored procedures and I want them to run in three separate connections in MySQL processlist.Is that possible?? pls help me out with this..

Is there any way to achieve parallelism in MySQL??

Comment: Will high cpu usage 400% affect insert statements??

Comment: Which OS are you using?  How many cores do you have?  *nix is very good about sharing the CPU.  I find that Windows stumbles more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rethink your understanding of the client/server structure used by MySQL. And also which part runs which task. A stored procedure is executed by the server and doesn't need a connection. A connection is needed between client and server to communicate. So, how can new connections improve the SP execution speed?

However, you can of course open 3 connections from your client (e.g. MySQL Workbench) to your server and have each run a stored procedure, so the server will execute them in parallel. Database servers are designed to run thousands of connections and execute thousands of queries all at the same time, however a single connection can only run a single command at a given time (there is usually a direct mapping of connection -> thread).

**In MySQL Workbench:** In order to open multiple connections to the same server simply start multiple SQL IDEs from the same tile on the home screen. Within an IDE instance all editors share the same connection (plus 2 extra ones for admin work).

Comment: thanks a lot @mike lischke.. I am asking how i can open multiple connections from mysql workbench or sqlyog??.. please guide me.. I am stuck with this for a week..

Comment: @kishorre - do some comparison timing and see how much improvement, if any, you get.  Report back.

Comment: If you queries are I/O-bound, you may find no improvement.  If CPU-bound you won't find any improvement if the number of connections is more than the number of CPU cores.  (Etc.)